# How to run scalatest specs with two different dependency injection containers?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a test suite that consists of scalatest spec files.  They all run fine on in-memory implementations on my DIC which is an implementation of the cake pattern.

Now I want to run the same suite of tests as integration tests meaning the in-memory implementations will be replaced by collections that talk to a database, github API's that are communicated with, etc.

- Should I be creating different sbt environments and place my di containers in two separate environments (functional and integration) where one is loaded depending on the environment?  What would be the best way of doing this?
- Can I somehow collect tests in a functional and integration test suite where the container is mixed in?  How would something like this work?  Where would it be defined?

  ```scala
  val functionalTestSuite = new TestSuite with FunctionalTestEnvironment
  val integrationTestSuite = new TestSuite with IntegrationTestEnvironment
  ```

I want to re-use my tests to prevent code duplication but I have a hard time figuring this out in scala as I'm pretty new to this language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making separate testing suites.  Later I could configure sbt to only run those files instead of having it automatically search for files.

The disadvantage of this is that it takes a lot of boilerplate to add the tests to the suite each time.  I hope somebody will edit my answer to remove the boilerplate.

```scala
class FunctionalTestingSuite extends Suites {
  override val nestedSuites : IndexedSeq[Suite] = {
    //val actorSystem = FunctionalSpec.createActorSystem
    IndexedSeq(

      new CodeRepositorySpec(FunctionalSpec.createActorSystem) with FunctionalTestEnvironmentHelper,

      new PipelineCollectionSpec(FunctionalSpec.createActorSystem) with FunctionalTestEnvironmentHelper,
      new PipelineControllerSpec with FunctionalTestEnvironmentHelper,
      new PipelineSpec(FunctionalSpec.createActorSystem) with FunctionalTestEnvironmentHelper,

      new JobCollectionSpec(FunctionalSpec.createActorSystem) with FunctionalTestEnvironmentHelper,
      new JobControllerSpec with FunctionalTestEnvironmentHelper,
      new JobSpec(FunctionalSpec.createActorSystem) with FunctionalTestEnvironmentHelper
    )
  }
}
```

The dependency injection container is injected by mixing in a trait each time, in this case `FunctionalTestEnvironmentHelper`.  In the integration environment, the `IntegrationTestEnvironmentHelper` is used.